# app.config and 64-bit machines

Tags: .net, connection-string, 32bit-64bit, app-config

I have an app that works fine on 32-bit systems, but fails on XP 64 bit systems.  I've tracked it down to the connection string defined in my app.config thus:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="IFDSConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=fdsdata;Initial Catalog=IFDS;
        Trusted_Connection=true;Connect Timeout=0"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I try to reference it in code, I find that the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings collection only contains the LocalSqlServer connection string from the machine.config file and not my custom string.

Another oddity is that it works fine when I run the app out of Visual Studio.  It is only when I run out of the release folder that the connection string does not get defined.  The application's .exe.config file is there in the release folder along with the .exe file and is up to date.

Comment: Have you tried replicating this in a really basic console app?  I'm using Win7 64-bit and haven't noticed anything like this.  So maybe it's specific to XP, or it's something other than app.config on 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually found the explanation here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/c25cd2c0-653d-4890-97b8-d2c9ceda2949/

In short, this behavior occurs when a manifest file for the application is used.  In that case, the framework looks for application_name.config, NOT application_name.exe.config.  One workaround is to rename the config file after building the app.  Another is to add the assemblyIdentity node to the manifest.  In my own case, I was able to simply delete the manifest file and life is good once again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the connection string to devenv.exe.config file.

This is located

**Visual Studio 2010**

$$InstallLocation$$\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

**Visual Studio 2008**

$$InstallLocation$$\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config